# Excel VBA cell color change with conditions

Tags: excel, vba

I'm kinda new at excel macro, and would like to learn how to do the following.

Let's say that I have column D as start date, column E as end date, and column J as status.

The content of J is 'Not Started', 'WIP' and 'Completed'

How can I set column J to display color changes when the following conditions are met:
1) Before Start date & not started color grey
2) within start and end date & 'WIP' color green
3) after end date & 'WIP' color red
4) within start and end date & ' not Started' color amber

Your assistance is much appreciated

Comment: Is my answer helpful for you?

Answer (score 1):

You can add formulas on cells or create your own function to change cell color. For details please check the links given below -

https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2013/10/29/excel-change-row-background-color/

[Color cells based on their value - VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20799880/color-cells-based-on-their-value-vba)